# Regex to extract information of (make a TSV from) 3 versions of a text “block”

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text paste of a GUI that turn out to form text "blocks", with each line containing different information about a specific entry. For the information I'd like to collect, there are 3 types and I don't know how to handle that. I'm thinking TSV would be a good output format. I'd prefer for the regex to be handled by Notepad++, but if that can't be accommodated, I'd really prefer the regex to be handled by a free and **easy** to use (& install if s/w) site or software.

The 3 types are in question are with a base price, also with a price on rebate, and no price at all, for all 3 the "block" 1st line should be included; the following contain the input and desired output of each. Here is what I've done so far for the type with both base price & price on rebate: `\R0\R\R(\w.*)\R(?:\w.*\R){4}[\w-].*\R.*CDN\$\s(\d+\.\d{2})\RCDN\$\s(\d+\.\d{2})\R(?:\w.*\R){3}`.

I had to use code blocks even though the following isn't code as blockquotes clumped lines.

Thank you kindly for your help

**INPUT**

```
0

South Park™: The Stick of Truth™
OVERALL REVIEWS:
OVERWHELMINGLY POSITIVE
RELEASE DATE:
3 MAR, 2014
-75%
CDN$ 39.99
CDN$ 9.99
Add to Cart
RPGComedyAdventureFunnyTurn-Based
Added on 8/9/2020 ( remove )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
South Park™: The Stick of Truth™    39.99   9.99
```

**INPUT**

```
0

Grand Theft Auto V
OVERALL REVIEWS:
VERY POSITIVE
RELEASE DATE:
13 APR, 2015
View Details
Open WorldActionMultiplayerAutomobile SimCrime
Added on 1/15/2020 ( remove )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Grand Theft Auto V
```

**INPUT**

```
0

System Shock
OVERALL REVIEWS:
NO USER REVIEWS
RELEASE DATE:
SUMMER 2021
CDN$ 51.49
Add to Cart
ActionAdventureCyberpunkSci-fiImmersive Sim
Added on 6/9/2020 ( remove )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
System Shock    51.49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `0\R+(.+)\R(?:(?!CDN)(?!^0$)[\s\S])+(?:\RCDN\$\h+(\d+\.\d+))?(?:\RCDN\$\h+(\d+\.\d+))?\R(?:(?!^0$)[\s\S])+`
- Replace with: $1 $2 $3\n
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Ihp9rH/1/)**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! See ultimate goal: ![Regex making TSV from 3 versions of Steam wishlist](https://i.imgur.com/pejSjXJ.png)